# How do I Create a Search bar in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please See the code below, I am trying to use Gsheets as a database for staff contact details, I need to make this searchable but find myself stuck.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
<script>
  var datags = <?!= JSON.stringify(data) ?>;
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet"ref="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <header class="text-center ">
          <h1>Age UK Essex Staff Directory</h1>
        </header>
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Desk Phone</th>
            <th>Mobile Phone</th>
            <th>Other Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>Postal Address</th>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    console.log(datags);
      jQuery.each(datags, function() {
          console.log(this);
        $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+this.firstname+'</td><td>'+this.lastname+'</td><td>'+this.service+'</td><td>'+this.role+'</td><td>'+this.location+'</td><td>'+this.deskphone+'</td><td>'+this.mobilephone+'</td><td>'
        +this.otherphone+'</td><td>'+this.email+'</td><td>'+this.fax+'</td><td>'+this.postaladdress+'</td></tr>')
      })
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code makes up my index.html file and the below makes up my google script code, I have tested this and it works as expected. What I need to do now is add a search bar that can be used to search any one of the cells and return matching data to the UI.  This is the part I'm stuck with and I was hoping someone can give me some guidance.

```
    function doGet(e){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12vq2W5Hm6rl8v_HBzHHOLHvZ5HW7fn892u_JHjEJ-oY');
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Staff');
      var range = sheet.getDataRange();
      var values = range.getValues();
      var holderArray = [];
      var HTMLTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

      Logger.log(values);
      var holder = '';
      for(x=1; x<values.length; x++){
      holderArray.push({
      "firstname" : values[x][0],
      "lastname" : values[x][1],
      "service" : values[x][2],
      "role" : values[x][3],
      "location" : values[x][4],
      "deskphone" : values[x][5],
      "mobilephone" : values[x][6],
      "otherphone" : values[x][7],
      "email" : values[x][8],
      "fax" : values[x][9],
      "postaladdress" : values[x][10]});
      }
      HTMLTemp.data = holderArray;
      var html = HTMLTemp.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return html;
}

   function myFunction1(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12vq2W5Hm6rl8v_HBzHHOLHvZ5HW7fn892u_JHjEJ-oY');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Staff');
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    var holderArray = [];
    var HTMLTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

    Logger.log(values);
    var holder = '';
    for(x=1; x<values.length; x++){
    holderArray.push({
      "firstname" : values[x][0],
      "lastname" : values[x][1],
      "service" : values[x][2],
      "role" : values[x][3],
      "location" : values[x][4],
      "deskphone" : values[x][5],
      "mobilephone" : values[x][6],
      "otherphone" : values[x][7],
      "email" : values[x][8],
      "fax" : values[x][9],
      "postaladdress" : values[x][10]});
  }
      HTMLTemp.data = holderArray;
      var html = HTMLTemp.evaluate().setWidth(1020).setHeight(800);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Age UK Essex Staff 
      Directory');
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: What is `datags`? Where are you setting it?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I have added my full code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search bar with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280868/search-bar-with-jquery)